# "href" parameter only onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I have following problem. I have pre-defined `href` on link which I can't change or remove in ***html***. I need to have this `href` only `onmouseover`. So I removed it with:

`document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0].removeAttribute("href");`

Now I need to add this `href` back but only `onmouseover`, so in default there will be no `href` attribute and `onmouseover` will enable it. But this and similar solutions doesn't work:

`document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0].onmouseover="this.href = 'urlHere';"`

Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is the kind of thing that will break accessibility.

Comment: Why would you try to add an href attribute on mouseover? If it's present, it doesn't do anything unless the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, ***you almost certainly shouldn't do this***, because it will [break accessibility](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2019-02-15-creating-valid-and-accessible-links/#toc_Start-with-valid-HTML). If you just want to change some styling, use CSS and [the `:hover` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

*However*, if you really did have a legitimate use case for this, the best way to do it would be using a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap):

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link-class-name')

const map = new WeakMap()

links.forEach(link => {
    map.set(link, link.href)

    link.removeAttribute('href')

    link.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => link.href = map.get(link))
    link.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => link.removeAttribute('href'))
})
```

`WeakMap`s are cool because they allow you to store arbitrary metadata about arbitrary objects in a way that can be garbage collected when it's no longer needed. This makes them perfect for storing and retrieving data about DOM nodes.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! Ofcourse i know accessibility issues in this :) but i have a use for this.

Comment: @MartinTK It's quite likely that what you _think_ is a legitimate use case for this would actually be better served by some other solution. But as you haven't provided that information, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event listener to the document object, if you hover over the `<a>` tag then add the link otherwise if you hover outside of it remove the href attribute.

Example:

```js
const link = document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0];

link.removeAttribute("href");

document.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');
  } else {
    link.removeAttribute('href');
  }

})
```

```html
<a class="class" href="http://www.google.com">Google site</a>
```